# Restsharp not replacing request placeholder with urlSegment

Tags: c#, rest, restsharp

I have a request of type POST and the resource looks like this:
"stuff/user/{userid}/login" the problem is that when adding the user id parameter, the placeholder wont be replaced.

Here is the code:

```
RestRequest request = new RestRequest();
                request.Resource = "stuff/user/{userid}/login";
                request.Method = RestSharp.Method.POST;
                request.AddParameter("userid", usuario, ParameterType.UrlSegment);
```

When debugging, request.Resource = "stuff/user/{userid}/login"

What is happening?

Answer (score 2):

When the request gets executed it will replace the parameter

```
var client = new RestClient("http://example.com");
var result = client.Execute(request)
```

Then result.ResponseUri will be http://example.com/stuff/user/[valueOfusuario]/login

/Michael